# Thread safety / Invoke method causes StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, thread-safety, invoke

This is an app that uses WMI to fetch Local Administrator group members on a remote computer. In an attempt to make threadsafe calls to update my main UI from within Background Worker I am getting a StackOverflowException. I have copied the example from another thread on Stack. Could someone help me to identify the cause?

```
private void getLocalAdministrators(string serverName)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Management.ManagementScope scope = new System.Management.ManagementScope("\\\\" + serverName + "\\root\\cimv2");
            scope.Connect();

            StringBuilder qs = new StringBuilder();
            qs.Append("SELECT PartComponent FROM Win32_GroupUser WHERE GroupComponent = \"Win32_Group.Domain='" + serverName + "',Name='" + "Administrators'\"");

            System.Management.ObjectQuery query = new System.Management.ObjectQuery(qs.ToString());
            System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

            foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject group in searcher.Get())
            {
                string groupDetails = serverName + tab + group["PartComponent"].ToString() + tab;

                string domainPart = groupDetails.Split('=')[1];
                domainPart = domainPart.Replace("\"","").Replace(",Name","");

                string accountPart = groupDetails.Split('=')[2];
                accountPart = accountPart.Replace("\"", "");

                if (query != null)
                {
                    updateUISafely(serverName + tab + domainPart + tab + accountPart);
                }
                else
                {
                    updateUISafely("Error with: " + serverName);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            updateUISafely("Error with: " + serverName + ". " + ex.Message);
        }

    }

    public delegate void ProcessResultDelegate(string result);
    void updateUISafely(string result)
    {
        if (textBox2.InvokeRequired)
        {
            var d = new ProcessResultDelegate(updateUISafely);
            d.Invoke(result);
        }
        else
        {
            textBox2.AppendText(result + nl);
        }
    }


    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] strArray;
        strArray = textBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        int objectCount = strArray.Count();
        int count = 0;

        foreach (string str in strArray)
        {
            getLocalAdministrators(str);
            count++;
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((100 * count) / objectCount);
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string item in resultsList)
        {
            textBox2.AppendText(item + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        btnGet.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are invoking (aka calling) the delegate, causing it to repeatedly call `updateUISafely` without ever invoking on the UI thread.

You should call `Invoke` on the form/control instead providing the delegate as parameter.

Use:

```
this.Invoke(d);
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a while since I last did it and although I had a previous code example in front of me I didn't spot my mistake. All resolved now.